# Multiline regex overjumps items

Tags: regex, scala

This is my string I want to regex:

```
(roman)
item(Hello
World)
item(Foo bar)
```

The regex `"item\\(.*\\)".r` only works if there are no `\n` characters.
I've found out, that `(?s)` should help.
But `"(?s)item\\(.*\\)".r` includes also the second item.

My desired result is something like this `List(Hello\nWorld, Foo bar)`.
Is there a regex with this notation possible? Or what is an notation, which allows the usage of multiline regexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (with *str* set to your string above):

```
"""item\(([^)]*)\)""".r.findAllMatchIn(str).map{_.group(1)}.toList
```

It's usually better to look for a sequence of characters that are *not* the final character, rather than any character.